# Move pageViewController with button (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a pageViewController which brings different images to the screen on each swipe.  The paging works with the gesture great.  However, I am trying to implement a button which does the paging as well.  I have a button on the top left called "Back" and a button on the top right called "Next".  I can't get these buttons to work.

Note:  OnboardingChildViewController is the child controller of LoginSignUpController

**Code**:
LoginSignUpViewController.m:

```
#pragma mark - Paging delegate

- (OnboardingChildViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    OnboardingChildViewController *childViewController = [[OnboardingChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OnboardingChildViewController" bundle:nil];
    childViewController.index = index;
    return childViewController;

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(OnboardingChildViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Decrease the index by 1 to return
    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(OnboardingChildViewController *)viewController index];

    index++;

    if (index == 5) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
// The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
// The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
return 0;
}
```

OnboardingChildViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    switch(self.index)
    {
    case 0: {
        self.dismissButton.hidden = true;
        self.onboardingImage.image = nil;
        [self.nextButton setTitle:@"Take a Tour" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.onboardingDescription.hidden = true;
        self.index = 0;
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        self.dismissButton.hidden = false;
        self.onboardingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"onboardingImage1.png"];
        self.onboardingDescription.text = @"Follow users to see their content in your feed";
        self.index = 1;
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        self.dismissButton.hidden = false;
        self.onboardingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"onboardingImage2.png"];
        self.onboardingDescription.text = @"Listen to Stations based on your interest";
        self.index = 2;
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        self.dismissButton.hidden = false;
        self.onboardingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"onboardingImage3.png"];
        self.onboardingDescription.text = @"Easily Search for Users, Posts, and Stations";
        self.index = 3;
        break;
    }
    default: {
         self.dismissButton.hidden = false;
        self.onboardingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"onboardingImage4.png"];
        [self.nextButton setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.onboardingDescription.text = @"Post Photos, Videos, Audio, and Live Video to Stations";
        self.index = 4;
        break;
    }
}

}


- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {
   //NEED TO MOVE PAGEVIEWCONTROLLER BACK.... self.index--?


}
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender {
    //NEED TO MOVE PAGEVIEWCONTROLLER FORWARD.... self.index++?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `setViewControllers` and pass in the ViewController you want to display

https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: